# Doubled Viewstate field ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, templates, render

Please help guys, the issue is - i have main page and want to render another page inside it using Server.Execute('demo.aspx')

All is fine except one thing - main page generates one Viewstate field and inner (called / extern) page creates new one and when i try to do POST submit it generates an error with ViewstateException.

The question is - how to prevent generating Viewstate for Server.Execute() i.e. inner page?

Thanks in advance, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually doing exactly what it should. [`Server.Execute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw97w238.aspx) basically will insert the second page's content into the first page, including ViewState.

To remedy your problem, are you able to disable ViewState on the page that's being called (demo.aspx)?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="false" CodeBehind="demo.aspx.cs"
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately i tried to disbale Viewstate for ContentPlaceHolder (main and inner page), Content for these place holders (both pages), for both Master and Content pages, then tried to do this using web.config - <pages EnableViewstate="false"> - nothing is working

Comment: Though only now i have realized that my inner page contains its own FORM (runat=server) and this is the reason! I just removed this form at all and now all is working great :)